# How can I set up canned response in Android Messages app?

Tags: sms

Is there a way to configure Android Messages with a list of custom templates? For instance:

- "I'm away right now."
- "Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you soon"
- ...

In the Android Messages app, I could then select one of these custom messages when responding to someone, or when contacting someone by SMS for the first time.

Comment: @beeshyams I'm talking about the app "Android Messages" by Google https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging&hl=en_US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to set up templates in the Google messaging app. Closest is *Smart reply* which suggests replies based over time but no where close to templates

You will need to use apps that do this, as [claimed](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3250528/android/text-message-templates-android.html) (not tested by me) or consider [other alternatives](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=android+text+message+templates&btnG=Search&hl=en-IN&gbv=1)